# Is it possible to load Gutenberg on custom fields?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I want to have 3 versions of same page, which will be served from same url. So I want to have 3 Gutenberg instances, one for main post content and 2 for custom fields that I have. Is it possible? With tinymce(Wordpress’s previous editor based on tinymce), it was possible even 15 years ago but I could not find info about loading Gutenberg on a text area custom field.

Comment: Is your goal like A/B content testing? What do the custom fields control? My first thought is it sounds more like a page template that then has a query to load the 2 other pieces of content? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to load different content for different countries from the same page url (without changing url of page). So I want to have same Gutenberg editor for all text area elements (custom fields) on the same editing screen. Alternatively I can use multiple pages for different content but this time I need to check whether page has another related page for different country. With custom field, all data is already loaded, I need to show only custom field in related country (and I dont need to do custumization for search, sitemap, feed functionalities).